# az cli run-command invoke with multiple command line parameters fails

Tags: python, azure, argparse, azure-cli

I am trying to execute a remote python script with command line arguments. The python script is developed using argparse. As we know argparse takes input with `-/--` as the parameter name. Passing this in the `--parameters` of az cli throws weird errors.

**Question**
How to pass python argparse like parameters for the python script using the `az run-command invoke`

---

**Some sample tries and output**

**Try - 1**

```
az vm run-command invoke     --resource-group MDC_VME_DEV_EUS  \
   --name ubuntumemsql002     --command-id RunShellScript  \
   --scripts /mnt/workspace/scripts/test.py   \
  --parameters "-i /mnt/workspace/data/indata" "-o /mnt/workspace/data/outdata" "--input_compressed_data" "--output_compressed_data" "-a 600" "-p 0.1" "-b 600 1200 1800"  "-s 1543275000"

az vm run-command invoke: ' /mnt/workspace/data/outdata' is not a valid value for '--output'. See 'az vm run-command invoke --help'.
```

**Try - 2**

```
 bash-4.4# az vm run-command invoke    \
 --resource-group MDC_VME_DEV_EUS \
    --name ubuntumemsql002     \ 
--command-id RunShellScript    \
 --scripts /mnt/workspace/scripts/test.py  \
   --parameters "-i /mnt/workspace/data/indata -o /mnt/workspace/data/outdata --input_compressed_data --output_compressed_data -a 600 -p 0.1 -b 600 1200 1800  -s 1543275000"

Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 36317037-4cfb-429e-b113-f8995d3419fb. VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'RunCommandLinux'. 
Error message: "Enable failed: failed to execute command: command terminated with exit status=2
    [stdout]

    [stderr]
    /var/lib/waagent/run-command/download/7/script.sh: 1: export: /mnt/workspace/data/indata: bad variable name

".
```

**Try - 3**

```
bash-4.4# az vm run-command invoke    \
--resource-group MDC_VME_DEV_EUS \
--name ubuntumemsql002  \
--command-id RunShellScript \
--scripts /mnt/workspace/scripts/test.py \
--parameters "-i /mnt/workspace/data/indata -o /mnt/workspace/data/outdata --input_compressed_data --output_compressed_data -a 600 -p 0.1 -b 600 1200 1800  -s 1543275000" --verbose
    Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 9efaf01c-3d7b-473a-90c8-802d63b6ccf0. VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'RunCommandLinux'. 
Error message: "Enable failed: failed to execute command: command terminated with exit status=2
    [stdout]

    [stderr]
    /var/lib/waagent/run-command/download/8/script.sh: 1: export: /mnt/workspace/data/indata: bad variable name
    ".
```

**Try - 4**

```
bash-4.4# az vm run-command invoke \
>     --resource-group MDC_VME_DEV_EUS \
>     --name ubuntumemsql002 \
>     --command-id RunShellScript \
>     --scripts /mnt/workspace/scripts/test.py \
>     --parameters -i /mnt/workspace/data/indata -o /mnt/workspace/data/outdata --input_compressed_data --output_compressed_data -a 600 -p 0.1 -b 600 1200 1800  -s 1543275000
az vm run-command invoke: error: argument --parameters: expected at least one argument
usage: az vm run-command invoke [-h] [--verbose] [--debug]
                                [--output {json,jsonc,table,tsv,yaml}]
                                [--query JMESPATH]
                                [--resource-group RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME]
                                [--name NAME] --command-id COMMAND_ID
                                [--scripts SCRIPTS [SCRIPTS ...]]
                                [--parameters PARAMETERS [PARAMETERS ...]]
                                [--subscription _SUBSCRIPTION]
                                [--ids ID [ID ...]]
```

**Try - 5**

```
 bash-4.4# az vm run-command invoke \
>     --resource-group MDC_VME_DEV_EUS \
>     --name ubuntumemsql002 \
>     --command-id RunShellScript \
>     --scripts /mnt/workspace/scripts/test.py \
>     --parameters \-i /mnt/workspace/data/indata \-o /mnt/workspace/data/outdata --input_compressed_data --output_compressed_data \-a 600 \-p 0.1 \-b 600 1200 1800  \-s 1543275000
az vm run-command invoke: error: argument --parameters: expected at least one argument
usage: az vm run-command invoke [-h] [--verbose] [--debug]
                                [--output {json,jsonc,table,tsv,yaml}]
                                [--query JMESPATH]
                                [--resource-group RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME]
                                [--name NAME] --command-id COMMAND_ID
                                [--scripts SCRIPTS [SCRIPTS ...]]
                                [--parameters PARAMETERS [PARAMETERS ...]]
                                [--subscription _SUBSCRIPTION]
                                [--ids ID [ID ...]]
bash-4.4#
```

**Direct VM CLI Try**

And, just to confirm, the same command executes perfectly, when I run them in the CLI

```
/mnt/workspace/scripts/test.py -i /mnt/workspace/data/indata -o /mnt/workspace/data/outdata --input_compressed_data --output_compressed_data -a 600 -p 0.1 -b 600 1200 1800  -s 1543275000
ReportInfo( input_file_name='/mnt/workspace/data/indata/s22k-1543290398518-VV5X13.gz'output_file_name='/mnt/workspace/data/outdata/s22k-1543290398518-VV5X13-data-1543275000.gz'result='Success' )
ReportInfo( input_file_name='/mnt/workspace/data/indata/s22k-1543290398518-VV5X11.gz'output_file_name='/mnt/workspace/data/outdata/s22k-1543290398518-VV5X11-data-1543275000.gz'result='Success' )
ReportInfo( input_file_name='/mnt/workspace/data/indata/s22k-1543290398518-VV5X12.gz'output_file_name='/mnt/workspace/data/outdata/s22k-1543290398518-VV5X12-data-1543275000.gz'result='Success' )
ReportInfo( input_file_name='/mnt/workspace/data/indata/s22k-1543290398518-VV5X15.gz'output_file_name='/mnt/workspace/data/outdata/s22k-1543290398518-VV5X15-data-1543275000.gz'result='Success' )
ReportInfo( input_file_name='/mnt/workspace/data/indata/s22k-1543290398518-VV5X14.gz'output_file_name='/mnt/workspace/data/outdata/s22k-1543290398518-VV5X14-data-1543275000.gz'result='Success' )
```

---

**Some example (as suggested in comments)**

**Run - 1**

```
bash-4.4# az vm run-command invoke \
>     --resource-group MDC_VME_DEV_EUS \
>     --name ubuntumemsql002 \
>     --command-id RunShellScript \
>     --scripts /mnt/workspace/scripts/test.py \
>     --parameters "\-i" "/mnt/workspace/data/indata" "\-o" "/mnt/workspace/data/outdata" "\--input_compressed_data" "\--output_compressed_data" "\-a" "600" "\-p" "0.1" "\-b" "600 1200 1800"  "\-s" "1543275000"
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 70f7646e-fa94-4104-8067-e42b92470803. VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'RunCommandLinux'. Error message: "Enable failed: failed to execute command: command terminated with exit status=2
[stdout]

[stderr]
/var/lib/waagent/run-command/download/9/script.sh: 1: export: 1200: bad variable name
```

**Run - 2**

```
bash-4.4# az vm run-command invoke \
>     --resource-group MDC_VME_DEV_EUS \
>     --name ubuntumemsql002 \
>     --command-id RunShellScript \
>     --scripts /mnt/workspace/scripts/prepare_data_for_memsql_ingest.py \
>     --parameters "\-i" "/mnt/workspace/data/indata" "\-o" "/mnt/workspace/data/outdata" "\--input_compressed_data" "\--output_compressed_data" "\-a" "600" "\-p" "0.1" "\-b" "600" "1200" "1800"  "\-s" "1543275000"
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: e460bfa4-286e-43c3-8a60-6f74b78c7e85. VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'RunCommandLinux'. Error message: "Enable failed: failed to execute command: command terminated with exit status=2
[stdout]

[stderr]
usage: PROG [-h] -i INPUT_DIR -o OUT_DIR
            (--input_compressed_data | --input_uncompressed_data)
            (--output_compressed_data | --output_uncompressed_data) -a
            AGGREGATE_INTERVAL -p {<__main__.Range object at 0x7fd86f8c49d0>}
            -b BACKDATE_INTERVAL_LIST [BACKDATE_INTERVAL_LIST ...] -s
            START_EPOCH
PROG: error: argument -i/--input_dir is required
".
```

---

Comment: Try `--parameters "\-i" "/mnt/workspace/data/indata" "\-o" "/mnt/workspace/data/outdata" ...`

Comment: @Sraw : It doesn't work. Same issue!!!

Comment: Same as which one?

Comment: @Sraw : I have added the suggested try output in the main question. HTH!

Comment: If the answer is helpful you can accept it. Or need more help please give me the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@kumar_m_kiran - Please try this out and let me know if it works:

```
az vm run-command invoke     --resource-group MDC_VME_DEV_EUS  \
   --name ubuntumemsql002     --command-id RunShellScript  \
   --scripts "python /mnt/workspace/scripts/test.py -i /mnt/workspace/data/indata -o /mnt/workspace/data/outdata --input_compressed_data --output_compressed_data -a 600 -p 0.1 -b 600 1200 1800 -s 1543275000"
```

Probably you need to run the script with "python" keyword in the beginning. Also you can provide all the parameters for your script within the scripts argument itself.

Answer (score 1):

With the test and the document, the CLI command just runs the shell script with the parameters using the `--parameters` in Linux VM. You can get the details from [Run Shell Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command) and [Available Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command#available-commands).

> Run Command uses the VM agent to run shell scripts within an Azure
>   Linux VM.

Then test with the `--debug` and the result here:

**Shell Script**
[image]
[image]
**Python Script**
[image]
[image]

The process is the same, but the shell script works and python script not. So it seems you just can run the python script as a shell script with the parameters like this:

```
az vm run-command invoke     --resource-group groupName  \
   --name vmName             --command-id RunShellScript  \
   --scripts "python /path/test.py arg1 arg2 arg3"
```